# c# - Substracting two times returns negative value

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm having problems when I'm trying to substract hr2 with hr1 in a specific situation, for example, when `hr1 = 13:00` and `hr2 = 15:00`, ok, the result is `02:00`. 
But when the values are: `hr1 = 22:00` and `hr2 = 02:00`, the result is `20:00`.
The result should be `04:00`.

```
 TimeSpan ts1 = hr1.Subtract(hr2).Duration();
 TextBox1.Text = ts1.ToString();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you want, but how you currently try to achieve it makes no sense. 22 hours minus 20 hours is 2 hours, which is correct.

You probably want this:

```
new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0) - new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 22, 0, 0)
```

You don't want to subtract TimeSpan's, you want to subtract dates (fake dates in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Invoking `Duration()` will always result in a positive `TimeSpan`.  The problem is coming from the fact that you are discarding days in your calculation.  22:00-02:00 *is* 20:00.  I believe you are expecting it to be 04:00 because 02:00 represents "tomorrow."  If that is what you want, you will need to calculate 22:00-(02:00+24:00) which will give you -04:00, which will become 04:00 when you invoke `Duration()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subtract two "spans", or durations, of time--not fixed points in time.  What your code is currently saying is, I want to subtract two hours from twenty hours (which is indeed twenty hours).  Instead, you need to use `DateTime`s.  The hard part is going to be deciding the date for your timespans.  I would rework the code to use `DateTime`s and preserve the "moments" in time that you are actually attempting to calculate.

Edit: Converting from a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` can cause you to lose information that affects the outcome of the result:

```
var ts1 = new DateTime (1, 1, 1, hr1.Hours, hr1.Minutes, hr1.Seconds, hr1.Milliseconds) -
          new DateTime (1, 1, 1, hr2.Hours, hr2.Minutes, hr2.Seconds, hr2.Milliseconds);
```

is different than:

```
var ts1 = new DateTime (1, 1, 1, hr1.Hours, hr1.Minutes, hr1.Seconds, hr1.Milliseconds) -
          new DateTime (1, 1, 2, hr2.Hours, hr2.Minutes, hr2.Seconds, hr2.Milliseconds);
```

or:

```
var ts1 = new DateTime (1, 1, 2, hr1.Hours, hr1.Minutes, hr1.Seconds, hr1.Milliseconds) -
          new DateTime (1, 1, 1, hr2.Hours, hr2.Minutes, hr2.Seconds, hr2.Milliseconds);
```

Which is why you need to maintain the "point in time" with a `DateTime`.